# Out of range value for column 'number' at row 1

Tags: mysql, sql

запрос:
INSERT INTO car (number) VALUES ('221.3');

структура:
number   -  decimal(6,4)

Результат:Out of range value for column 'number' at row 1

Comment: Определите тип, например, так:  decimal(6,2)

Comment: decimal(6,4) - это всего 6 знаков, из которых 4 после запятой. То есть от -99.9999 до 99.9999.